# how do l convert the following code into a class based component

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAccounts} from '..//../actions/accounts';


const BillLines = (props) => {

  // componentDidMount() {
  //       props.getAccounts();
  //   }
  useEffect(() => {
        if(!props.fetched) {
            props.getAccounts();
        }
        console.log('mount it!');
    }, []);

  const { accounts } = props;

  console.log(accounts)


  let debitAccounts = accounts.length > 0
    && accounts.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <option key={i} value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
    )
  }, this);

  return (
    props.lines.map((val, idx) => {
      let debit_account = `debit_account-${idx}`, amount = `amount-${idx}`
```

how do l convert the following code into class based component in react.js. What do l suppose to look at first in order to come up with a working solution. Anyone to help please ??

Comment: The answer is you don't. The React team has recommended moving away from class-based components and instead using functional components with hooks, which is a much simpler model to handle lifecycle events. Why do you wan to?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article:

https://medium.com/@olinations/10-steps-to-convert-a-react-class-component-to-a-functional-component-with-hooks-ab198e0fa139

It shows how to turn a class component to a functional components...It will have all you need to do what you want. (basically you need to do the opposite)

Comment: let me try to familiarise my self with your documentation will give you a proper feed back when done. Thank you so much